# OpenLDAP configuration via terminal on MacOS 12 and above (Monterey and Ventura)

Tags: macos, terminal, monterey, ventura, ldap

I want to make Mac machines, in my network, use my LDAP Server to authenticate users. To do so, I tried the GUI tool "Directory Utility" and configured everything as desired and took a copy of following files which were created/modified after the attributes mappings and LDAP configuration:

```
/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/Contacts.plist
/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/Search.plist
/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/ldapserver.mycompany.com.plist
```

Now I want to deploy these files to the other Mac machines through Puppet to configure all of Mac machines to do the authentication process via the Ldap Server.

But the problem is I do not have permission to write into those paths (even as a root). Apparently (I guess) the paths can be written through tools like Directory Utility (and maybe `dscl`).

I used to use this approach before Big Sur and it was working perfectly fine but now I can't get it work.
I need a way to configure this through terminal so I can automate (puppetise) the process. I googled it a lot but the only useful thing was `dscl` command which does not sound like it can be used to configure an LDAP node.

I'm completely open to any other way to configure this and the only requirement is that it should be done through terminal.

In another sense, is there any equivalent command-line utility for Directory Utility GUI?

Comment: Isn't `dscl` the equivalent command-line utility for Directory Utility?

Comment: I think so but I can't get it work, the options are not like what I need. I have asked my question in a better way in [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452188/configure-ldap-through-command-line-not-directory-utility-on-ventura-and-monte) . Please take a look to see if you can help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure LDAP with a profile. Create a Configuration Profile using [Apple Configurator](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/apple-configurator) with an LDAP configuration payload. This gives you a .mobileconfig file.

[image]

If you don't have an MDM solution to deploy this, it appears you can no longer use a Puppet module like [`edestecd-mobileconfig_profile`](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/edestecd/mobileconfig_profile/readme) to apply profiles since Big Sur.

[The `profile -I` install option has been removed in Big Sur](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658667) and the Puppet module [`vanagandr42-mac_profile`](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/vanagandr42/mac_profile/readme) notes that it no longer works in Big Sur and later.

This means you will need to use an MDM solution to deploy the configuration profile automatically. For example, [Apple Business Essentials](https://www.apple.com/business/essentials/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need a way to do it through terminal at least

Comment: FYI, I have asked my question in another way (a better way in fact) in [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452188/configure-ldap-through-command-line-not-directory-utility-on-ventura-and-monte). Please take a look to see if you can help me in this case.