# Configure LDAP through command line (NOT Directory Utility) on Ventura and Monterey

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, plist, ldap

I can configure Directory Utility to make Mac machines (Monterey and above) authenticate users through my OpenLDAP (Ubuntu-based) server and everything works perfectly fine.

But I need to do it through terminal cause I have to automate the process and hold the machines in the desired state via Puppet.

I have three files named `Contacts.plist` `Search.plist` and `ldapserver.company.com.plist` and I want to place them (via Puppet) in the following paths respectively.

```
/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/Contacts.plist
/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/Search.plist
/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/ldapserver.company.com.plist
```

I am not allowed to do this even as a root although it used to work before the new Apple filesystem layout (some Read-Only issue). But now I cannot put these files in there unless I boot up in recovery mode (to get rid of Read-Only issue). I do not want to put the system in such state at all.

Apparently there is no way to create/replace such files in those paths and I have to configure it through some command-line tools (maybe like `dsconfigldap` or `dscl`).

What I have done so far is running the following command ([Found here](https://jamauai.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/how-to-bind-macs-to-server-via-command-line/))

```
dsconfigldap -fa ldapserver.company.com -n "My Company LDAP Server" -N
```

This creates `ldapserver.company.com.plist` in a binary format. I converted the file to an XML format and the content is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>ldapserver.company.com</string>
        <key>module options</key>
        <dict>
                <key>AppleODClient</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>Server Mappings</key>
                        <true/>
                </dict>
                <key>ldap</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>Denied SASL Methods</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>DIGEST-MD5</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>LDAP Referrals</key>
                        <false/>
                        <key>Use DNS replicas</key>
                        <false/>
                </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>node name</key>
        <string>/LDAPv3/ldapserver.company.com</string>
        <key>options</key>
        <dict>
                <key>connection idle disconnect</key>
                <integer>60</integer>
                <key>connection setup timeout</key>
                <integer>10</integer>
                <key>destination</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>host</key>
                        <string>ldapserver.company.com</string>
                        <key>other</key>
                        <string>ldap</string>
                        <key>port</key>
                        <integer>389</integer>
                </dict>
                <key>man-in-the-middle</key>
                <false/>
                <key>no cleartext authentication</key>
                <false/>
                <key>packet encryption</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>packet signing</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>query timeout</key>
                <integer>30</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>template</key>
        <string>Open Directory Server</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This configuration is all default and not desired by me (There is no mapping, the used port is 389 but I need 636, etc.). my desired config file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>ldapserver.company.com</string>
                <key>mappings</key>
        <dict>
                <key>attributes</key>
                <array>
                        <string>objectClass</string>
                </array>
                <key>function</key>
                <string>ldap:translate_recordtype</string>
                <key>recordtypes</key>
                <dict>
                      <key>dsRecTypeStandard:Automount</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>info</key>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>Group Object Classes</key>
                                        <string>OR</string>
                                        <key>Object Classes</key>
                                        <array>
                                                <string>automount</string>
                                        </array>
                                        <key>Search Base</key>
                                        <string>ou=automount,dc=company,dc=com</string>
                                </dict>
                        </dict>
                        <key>dsRecTypeStandard:Users</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>attributetypes</key>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:NFSHomeDirectory</key>
                                        <dict>
                                                <key>native</key>
                                                <string>homeDirectory</string>
                                        </dict>
                                </dict>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>Group Object Classes</key>
                                        <string>OR</string>
                                        <key>Object Classes</key>
                                        <array>
                                                <string>posixAccount</string>
                                                <string>inetOrgPerson</string>
                                                <string>shadowAccount</string>
                                        </array>
                                        <key>Search Base</key>
                                        <string>ou=current,dc=company,dc=com</string>
                                </dict>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
                <key>template</key>
                <string>LDAPv3</string>
        </dict>
        <key>module options</key>
        <dict>
                <key>AppleODClient</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>Server Mappings</key>
                        <false/>
                </dict>
                <key>ldap</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>Denied SASL Methods</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>DIGEST-MD5</string>
                                <string>NTLM</string>
                                <string>GSSAPI</string>
                                <string>CRAM-MD5</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>LDAP Referrals</key>
                        <false/>
                        <key>Use DNS replicas</key>
                        <false/>
                </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>node name</key>
        <string>/LDAPv3/ldapserver.company.com</string>
        <key>options</key>
        <dict>
                <key>connection idle disconnect</key>
                <integer>60</integer>
                <key>connection setup timeout</key>
                <integer>10</integer>
                <key>destination</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>host</key>
                        <string>ldapserver.company.com</string>
                        <key>other</key>
                        <string>ldaps</string>
                        <key>port</key>
                        <integer>636</integer>
                </dict>
                <key>man-in-the-middle</key>
                <false/>
                <key>no cleartext authentication</key>
                <false/>
                <key>packet encryption</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
                <key>packet signing</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>query timeout</key>
                <integer>30</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>template</key>
        <string>LDAPv3</string>
        <key>trusttype</key>
        <string>anonymous</string>
        <key>uuid</key>
        <string>blah-blah-blah-blah-blah</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I do not know how to use command-line tools to tweak that default file and write what I want.

I do not want any sort of GUI alternative (like Apple Configurator or Blueprint etc.). All I want is a way to configure those three files (hereinabove mentioned) only through command-line.

Please be aware that the desired config file might have some syntax error cause I did not copy the whole file as it was too long and I just copied a portion of it manually, which is prone to some syntax error. But I hope I have communicated what I intended to do.

I'm open to any other approaches if only it can be done through command line.

Any idea?